# ADO.Net in ASP.Net 5 MVC6?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to locate the Entity Data Model Wizard that allows you to populate the database schema into a DatabaseModel.edmx file so I can create my model based on that.

I've included the EntityFramework dlls into the project.json file but not too sure if in this new version of ASP.NET MVC this wizard is available anymore...

I've seen that the scaffolding that generates the Model classes is done through command line now but not sure if that has anything to do with the wizard I was talking about above.

Thanks!

Comment: Entity Framework 7 is "code first". No EDMX files. You just define your models in C# using the fluent syntax or attributes.

Comment: If you already have a database schema, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300777/is-there-an-entity-framework-7-database-first-poco-generator).

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> "Prior to EF7 there are two ways to store models, in the xml-based EDMX file format or in code. S**tarting with EF7 we will be retiring the EDMX format** and having a single code-based format for models."

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx