# Database First with EF7 in a Universal App

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, win-universal-app, entity-framework-core

I have a Sqlite database that I want to use in my UWP application With EF7, How can I create model from database with EF7?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300777/is-there-an-entity-framework-7-database-first-poco-generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox and create model from database
[SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox DLL](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300777/is-there-an-entity-framework-7-database-first-poco-generator) you should be able to create poco classes from an existing database. However, I have not tried this myself.

To summarize ErikEJs answer:

1. Get nuget packages EntityFramework.Commands and EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design
2. Run from the package manager console: *Scaffold-DbContext '<connectionString>' EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer* or *dnx ef dbcontext scaffold '<connectionString>' EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer

Comment: My databse is Sqlite not sqlserver

Comment: Ok my bad. I have never used Sqllite ut could there be equivalent packages available? Have you tried fetching EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design and running the command with "xxxxxxxxxx EntityFramework.Sqllite" instead?

Comment: it doesn't install in uwp application

Comment: =( Check out user2906881 answer, it looks promising