# How can I use the database that I already have got with entity7 in uwp?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, win-universal-app

I have always seen that in all tutorials, databases are made in the form of code-first, but already there is a sqlite database that I want to use in my project. And I want to use entity 7 too. To do so, I made some classes from my database by means of a dll but it didn't work. In fact, I made these classes so that I could use my own database. I didn't want it to create a new database. Any suggestions? Can you recommend me any links,because I couldn't find any useful link

I install Install-Package EntityFramework.SQLite –Pre and Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands –Pre and Install-Package SQLite.Net.Async-PCL /next step: with  Extension ،SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox generate classes from db and import my db into project in visual studio and set buildaction to content and in final add

```
 private async Task CopyDatabase()
{
    bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

    try
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("people.db");
        isDatabaseExisting = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        isDatabaseExisting = false;
    }

    if (!isDatabaseExisting)
    {
        StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("people.db");
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

into pp.xaml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an Entity Framework 7 Database-First POCO Generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300777/is-there-an-entity-framework-7-database-first-poco-generator)

Comment: Please post specifically what you have tried and what specifically didnt work. "I made some classes from my database by means of a dll but it didn't work. " is not enough information to help.

And if the thread Joel linked to is not relevant to you, explain why not. It sure looks relevant from here.

Comment: @esmoore68 ok,I edit my question...

Comment: You are mixing two technologies - EFCore has it's own class generator, as linked above..