# Can't generate code from EF Database First in ASP.NET 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

If I create a new console application, right click on the project and click **Add** -> **New Item**, I can select a lot of things including generation of tables code via EF Database First [image: Items when using Console Application].

Now if I create a new ASP.NET 5 web application, there are no EF-related items: [image: Add Item menu in ASP.NET 5 app]

Why is that so? I need to generate some code via EF Database First in my ASP.NET 5 application, how can I do that?

Comment: did you have Entity Framework dependency in your project.json?

Comment: @CrabMan try this solution,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29301370/1790663

Comment: @CrabMan try this solution,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29301370/1790663

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing Entity Framework package.  ASP.Net 5 has different approaches to install packages

Try this [tutorial](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.io/projects/mvc/en/1.0.0-beta7/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html)